# Object View override doesn't work on lightning and mobile

Tags: apex, visualforce, page-layout, mobile, view

I'm trying to replace the view of a standard page with my custom VF page.
This works great on the classic theme but not on the lightning theme and mobile application.

- In the VFP I checked "Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning
  Communities, and the mobile app".

[image]

- In the view override, I checked "Use the Salesforce Classic
  override".

[image]

Visualforce page (I don't think it has something to do with the page itself, it doesn't work with any page):

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity" lightningStylesheets="true">
    <apex:detail subject="{!Opportunity.Id}" relatedList="true" title="true" rendered="{!Opportunity.Amount < 10}" />
    <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!Opportunity.Amount > 10}">
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageMessage summary="Amount is less than 10" severity="warning" strength="3" />
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

I think that the problem is that for some reason the override doesn't even get fired on lightning experience. In the classic, I can see the URL changing to an APEX page, but on the lightning, it doesn't even bother trying to change the URL

- **URL in classic view (successful redirection):**

`https://c.eu16.visual.force.com/apex/xxx`

- **URL in lightning (doesn't redirect):**

`https://eu16.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Opportunity/0061t000001uPaDAAU/view`

**EDIT:**

Although I really don't like this option, I tried creating a lightning component using the following code:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="greeting" type="String" default="Hello" access="global" />
    <aura:attribute name="subject" type="String" default="World" access="global" />

    <div style="box">
      <span class="greeting">{!v.greeting}</span>, {!v.subject}!
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

and changed the view override to the created component. I couldn't get it working that way too.